# JMeter Regular expression for cookie: escape plus character

Tags: jmeter

This is my token cookie based extractor used into my jmeter:

[image]

I'm receiving:

[image]

However, I'm sending `"NOT FOUND"`:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Meta Characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) chapter of [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex) User Manual entry:

> Regular expressions use certain characters as meta characters - these characters have a special meaning to the RE engine. Such characters must be escaped by preceding them with `\` (backslash) in order to treat them as ordinary characters. Here is a list of the meta characters and their meaning (please check the ORO documentation if in doubt).
>
> `(` and `)`
> grouping
>
> `[` and `]`
> character classes
>
> `{` and `}`
> repetition
>
> `*`, `,` `+` and `?`
> repetition
>
> `.`
> wild-card character
>
> `\`
> escape character
>
> `|`
> alternatives
>
> `^` and `$`
> start and end of string or line

So you need to escape this `+` with the backslash like:

```
Set-Cookie: id_token=Bearer\+(.+?);
```

---

However be aware that you can use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) in order to get the cookie value:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. That's it, now you can refer the cookie value as `${COOKIE__id_token}` where required.